# Massive Water Effect

Tags: fluid-simulation

Is it possible to create an effect similar to the following link in Blender?

[Water splash simulation using realflow](https://vimeo.com/21886854)

The default fluid simulator works well for small scale effects but I am struggling to get it to produce convincing looks for massive water movement such as a cascade down a mountain side.